# AngularFire: npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am following the [documentation to get started](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/universal/getting-started.md) with AngularFire and Angular Universal. However after I run `npm install --save-dev @nguniversal/express-engine @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader express webpack-cli ts-loader ws xhr2` I get the following error:

[image: error output]

`npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree`

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^8.2.0" from @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@8.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader
npm ERR!   dev @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@"*" from the root project

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug? Any workarounds?

Comment: same here, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Glasnhost yes, see answer to question. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the documentation for angular fire is not up to date. Furthermore, the versions are very picky. I had success following [this tutorial](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/implement-angular-server-side-rendering/).

You can follow the same steps but with angular 11. Also, just don't even try deploying as a cloud function.